# select box with database interaction in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to set value differently and option differently in an Select tag

ex.

```
<select name="myselect">
<option value="1">one</option>
</select>
```

that mean i have two list from DB

1)one is Id of username to which i want to keep in value of select
2)second is username which is other. this i want to keep in between option tag

Please Help

thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that both of the list are in sync (in terms of index , i.e. user Abc from list a is at the top so id of the Abc in other list is at the top)

You can do it following way

```
<c:forEach var="idOfPerson" items="${listOfId}" varStatus="status">
  <option value="${idOfPerson}">${listOfNames[status.index]}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: yes indexes are same. I have two array came from Controller one is ${idList} other is ${username}

Comment: one is ${idList} other is ${username}

Comment: no i don't want 1 2 3 like that in value field...i want their corresponding IDs from DB

Comment: thats what your idList is holding just replace idOfPerson with idList in above code

Comment: i did same ..but in both cases i got diffrent valuess in <option value="1"></option> ....i dint got the value in betwwn option

Comment: I hope you have used `${username}` between option and it is accisible

Comment: oh sure.. can u plz tell me from where i have to do that...actually i m new to this forum